# How can you access Data on Vue if using arrow function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

We are using `Vue` and arrow function on methods. Since arrow function has no `this` keyword, how can we access the `data` like `list` or `object`

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      list: [],
      object: {},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit: (e) => {
      //How can access this here?
      //Im trying to access this.list
      console.log(this);
    }
  },
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use an arrow function as vue method if you need access to `this`. Why can't you simply use a normal function?

Comment: See the warning here: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended that you use arrow functions when declaring methods in your Vue components.

Why not just use someting like this?:

```
methods:{
  onSubmit(e){
   ...
  }
}
```

You can refer to other articles about to topics to get detailed info, since there are tons of replies on the same topic already:

[How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)